# svnnotify author field

Tags: perl, svn

We use svnnotify (i.e. [SVN::Notify](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SVN-Notify/)) in our svn post-commit hook.  Is it possible to include the userid of the author of the commit as the displayed name in the author field of the resulting email?  Authentication is through `mod_auth_mysql`.  We don't want the author to be "userid@domain of svn server" because there are no such email addresses - the committers all have external email addressses.  I'd like something like "userid via proj-svn" or something similar so that people can quickly identify who is responsible for the commit.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the post-commit hook to read the author userid from svnlook. Roughly:

```
my $svnlook = "/bin/svnlook";
my @info = `$svnlook info $repopath -r $revnum`;
my $author = shift @info;
```